# Loading Cassandra data into Titan/ Neo4J

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, cassandra, titan

I have wikipedia data in a Cassandra table (one row = one wiki article). Now I want to insert this into a graph database so I could see the relations between them. What I tried so far is to get records from Cassandra one by one and add them as nodes in Neo4J but this is very slow. Is there a way using Neo4J/ Titan where the data could be automatically taken from Cassandra and a graph be built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Neo4j

TL;DR; - there is no ready-to-use tool for your case, but `import-tool` exists

So, you want to migrate your data to Neo4j. Fastest way to do this is by using [import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html).

Plan:

- Dump your data from Cassandra to [CSV files](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-header-format.html).
- [Download](http://neo4j.com/download/) neo4j and extract somewhere
- Use `neo4j-import` tool (`bin/` directory), point to your CSV files and [import them](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-basic-example.html)

Import tool is **really fast** and can handle gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 2):

Titan offers bulk loading capability, which is recommended for loading large amounts of data:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/bulk-loading.html

Here is an older link that may also help, although some of material is dated:

http://thinkaurelius.com/2014/05/29/powers-of-ten-part-i/

There has to be a "program" of some kind to translate the Wikipedia data into nodes and edges for the property graph.  Maybe that is what you mean by "automatically" - asking if such an importer program exists out of the box.

I am not aware of a pre-existing program for Titan for Wikipedia data, although I am sure there is code somewhere.   This link might help with Neo4J:

https://github.com/mirkonasato/graphipedia